# Can a therapist heal on shabbat?

Tags: shabbat

I read that the laws changed where doctor's can heal on shabbat because of Macedonians on the Sabbath killed one thousand observant Jews. But how about when it comes to mental health? Can a therapist heal on patients on sabbath like give therapy? For example is one is feeling suicidal or depressed, they may break sabbath to save their life.

Comment: https://www.zaakah.org/shabbosyom-tov-hotline

Comment: @rosends wow thank you! joy

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.29b.12?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en

Comment: someone who is chas v'sholom contemplating suicide, helping this person would be piku'ach nefesh no?